TCPDF - Image on Whole Page
I have a problem with TCPDF, I would like the photo to cover the entire page, but the changes added to the code, i.e. resize, fitbox, fitonpage, do not introduce the desired changes. The photo should cover the entire space and it is as in the photo below. I'm attaching the standard code because I don't know what I'm doing wrong, i also tried set margin to 0 as you can see in my code.
To add appropriate values ​​I used this: What are the parameter of the Image() in tcpdf?



$pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'mm', array(148, 210), true, 'UTF-8', false);

    $pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $image_file_1 = $image_path . '1.png';
    $pdf->Image($image_file_1, 0, 0, 148, 210, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);

    $pdf->AddPage();

    $image_file_2 = $image_path . '2.png';
    $pdf->Image($image_file_2, $x = '0', $y = '0', $w = '148', $h = '210', $type = 'PNG', $link = '', $align = '', $resize = '', $dpi = 300, $palign = '', $ismask = false, $imgmask = false, $border = 0, $fitbox = false, $hidden = false, $fitonpage = '', $alt = false, $altimgs = array());




So what u get is a black image only ?

@KenLee Yeah, I want that black picture to cover whole page. But current methods with resize, fit, fitonpage were unsuccessful

Based on your code, it seems that you want the first page to have 1.png as background, and second page to have 2.png as background ? Do you have additional request(s) such as putting other text on top of the background images ??
